# Error:Delivery failed in skype channel

Tags: c#, azure, bots, skype-bots

Hi I am working on bot like by using latest update in azure I created web app bot suessfully, After that I tested the bot in test in web chat option in azure web app bot, There its working fine. I added the skype channel to the same bot so, when I am sending the user message in skype to bot then its showing the error like **delivery failed**.

[image]

[image]

I researched around the internet and could not find any solutions that solves my problem. Please help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].